# Transforming DataTable to List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, sql, list, reflection, datatable

I've already searched through StackOverflow (and other websites) about transforming a DataTable to List with reflection in C#.

My results until now are pretty good: I can reflect 200k lines in 3.5 seconds (0.5 seconds in hardcoded mode).

But my entities (the classes that represent my data, but I think you already know that) follow this pattern:

My database have columns like this (I don't actually do this, but you'll get the idea):

```
Table: Clients
Columns:
    ClientID, ClientName, ClientPhone, CityID[FK]
```

I'm using SqlConnection (MySqlConnection), so I have to hardcode my entities and transform the database result in a list of this entity. Like:

```
Select *, cit.* from Clients cli
Inner join Cities cit on (cit.CityID == cli.CityID)
Inner join Countries cou on (cou.CountryID == cit.CountID)
```

I don't know if this SQL is correct, but I think you got the idea. This should return some fields like this:

```
ClientID, ClientName, ClientPhone, CityID, CityName, CountryID, CountryName
```

Shoud result a `List<Client>`.

Here's the problem: I have 2 inner joins and I represent this data in my entities like this (I like the expression "like this"):

```
public class Client
{
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
    public string ClientPhone { get; set; }
    public City ClientCity { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
    public Country CityCountry { get; set; }
}

public class Country
{
    public int ContryID { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; }
}
```

So, if I have a `Client` object, I would get its country name by the expression `client.ClientCity.CityCountry.CountryName`. I call it a 3-level property acessor.

And I want to reflect it properly. Here is the main method to transform the DataTable into a List. My native language is Portuguese, but I tried to translate my comments to match my description above.

The idea of this code is: I try to find in the main class the column I have to set. If I don't find it, I search the property in the properties that are objects. Like CityName inside ClientCity inside Client. This code is a mess.

```
 public List<T> ToList<T>(DataTable dt) where T : new()
    {

        Type type= typeof(T);
        ReflectionHelper h = new ReflectionHelper(type);
        insertPropInfo(tipo);  //a pre-reflection work, I cache some delegates, etc..
        List<T> list = new List<T>();
        DataTableReader dtr = dt.CreateDataReader();
        while (dtr.Read())
        {
            T obj = new T();
            for (int i = 0; i < dtr.FieldCount; i++)
            {
                GetObject(ref obj, tipo, dtr.GetName(i), dtr.GetValue(i));
            }
            list.Add(obj);
        }

        return lista;

    }
        //ref T obj: the object I create before calling this method
        //Type classType: the type of the object (say, Client)
        //string colName: this is the Database Column i'm trying to fill. Like ClientID or CityName or CountryName.
        //colLineData: the data I want to put in the colName.

    public void GetObject<T>(ref T obj, Type classType, string colName, object colLineData) where T : new()
    {


        //I do some caching to reflect just once, and after the first iteration, I think all the reflection I need is already done.
        foreach (PropertyInfo info in _classPropInfos[classType])
        {
            //If the current PropertyInfo is a valuetype (like int, int64) or string, and so on
            if (info.PropertyType.IsValueType || info.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                //I think string.Equals is a little faster, but i had not much difference using "string" == "string"
                if (info.Name.Equals(colName)) //did I found the property?

                    if (info.PropertyType != typeof(char)) //I have to convert the type if this is a Char. MySql returns char as string.
                    {
                        _delegateSetters[info](obj, colLineData); //if it isn't a char, just set it.
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        _delegateSetters[info](obj, Convert.ChangeType(colLineData, typeof(char)));
                    }
                break;
            }
            else //BUT, if the property is a class, like ClientCity:
            {
                //I reflect the City class, if it isn't reflected yet:
                if (!_classPropInfos.ContainsKey(info.PropertyType))
                {
                    insertPropInfo(info.PropertyType);
                }
                //now I search for the property:
                Boolean foundProperty = false;
                object instance = _delegateGetters[info](obj); //Get the existing instance of ClientCity, so I can fill the CityID and CityName in the same object.

                foreach (PropertyInfo subInfo in _classPropInfos[info.PropertyType])
                {
                    if (subInfo.Name.Equals(colName))//did I found the property?
                    {
                        if (instance == null)
                        {
                            //This will happen if i'm trying to set the first property of the class, like CityID. I have to instanciate it, so in the next iteration it won't be null, and will have it's CityID filled.
                            instance = _initializers[info.PropertyType]();//A very fast object initializer. I'm worried about the Dictionary lookups, but i have no other idea about how to cache it.
                        }
                        _delegateSetters[subInfo](instance, colLineData);//set the data. This method is very fast. Search about lambda getters & setters using System.Linq.Expression.
                        foundProperty = true;
                        break;//I break the loops when I find the property, so it wont iterate anymore.
                    }

                }
                if (foundProperty)//if I found the property in the code above, I set the instance of ClientCity to the Client object.
                {
                    _delegateSetters[info](obj, instance);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

There is a problem with this code: I can reach the CityID and CityName, and fill it. But CountryID and CountryName wont. Because this code can do a 2-level reflection, I need some recursive-approach to fill many levels I need. I tried to do this BUT i got so many stack overflows and null reference exceptions I almost gave up.

This code would make it much easier to fetch database rows, Did you already find some library or anything that does what I want? If not, how could I achieve a n-level reflection to make a proper List from a DataTable?

Comment: A simple (to learn) and fast (to use) ORM. Use [dapper](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/)

Comment: Grab the `Dapper` library to do the database work, and it will also handle the mapping. You won't be able to do `SELECT *` stuff; but you shouldn't be anyway.

Comment: If you want to improve reflection performance, I recommend investing some time learning the `Reflection.Emit` namespace and/or expression trees.

Comment: i'm already using expression trees, i cache them in delegate[Setters|Getters] dictionary. I don't know why I left this name when I changed the approach.

Comment: Steve, i'll take a look at it.

Comment: @RicardoPieper, absolutely it will be a well spent time. Use it for one day and you will wonder how you had done before

Comment: Well, i tested dapper and it didn't do what I expected. It doesn't fill the sub-objects in the class, and also can't handle boolean values from MySql :(

Comment: @Steve forget what I said, dapper can handle the sub-objects. It still can't handle boolean values. Do you know why? (didn't tried to solve yet)

Comment: The authors of Dapper are between the most respected writers in this site. Ask a question and tag it `Dapper`

Comment: @Steve, I want to mark you as the answerer. Can you post some answer mentioning Dapper?

Comment: @RicardoPieper written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is really common and practically every ORM in circulation addresses this question.
Of course changing an already written application to take advantage of an ORM is often unpractical, but there are some simple ORM that are really easy to add to an existing application and let you replace incrementally the already written code.

One of these ORMs is [DAPPER](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/). It consists of just one source file that you can include directly in the same project with your POCO classes and repository methods (Or just reference the compiled assembly). It is really easy to learn and it is incredibly fast considering the complexity of the work to be carried out. Not to mention that the authors of this little gem are regularly on this site answering questions on their work. Just do a search with the `#dapper` tag

The only nuisances that I have found to date are the mapping one-to-one from your POCO properties and the field names and also the sometime eluding rules between PK and FK when your keys are not named `ID`. But that's me that I still haven't fully understood these rules.

Comment: I ended up "wrapping" dapper to fit my needs. My database fields follow a pattern that doesn't allow me to just put a field called `ID`. My examples are kinda fake, they're actually like CID_ID (for cities), CLI_ID(for clients) and so on. It's kind of awful to put it in c#, but for us here at my work, it's easy to know what the attribute holds. I also took a look at the dapper source, it's awesome, I can feel art in it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use [EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx). It will automate all this work.

Comment: To be more broad I would recommend an Object-relational mapper (ORM)

Comment: Already considered, but this is not my decision, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

This is based on you getting a dataset with the 3 tables and creating the proper DataRelation.
On your particular case(200k lines) i dont know how it will perform but shouldnt be that bad :).

Your calling code could be something like this:

```
List<Clients> clients = Test.CreateListFromTable<Clients>(ds.Tables["Clients"]);
```

Remember as i said its based in you fettching the dataset and creating the relations.
Next here is the class with the methods in question(ClientsToCity and CityToCountry are the names of the datarelations,you can place your own):

```
    public class Test
    {
        // function that set the given object from the given data row
        public static void SetItemFromRow<T>(T item, DataRow row) where T : new()
        {
            foreach (DataColumn c in row.Table.Columns)
            {
                PropertyInfo prop = item.GetType().GetProperty(c.ColumnName);

                if (prop != null && row[c] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    prop.SetValue(item, row[c], null);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (c.ColumnName == "CityID")
                    {
                        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(City));

                        SetItemFromRow<City>(obj as City, row.GetChildRows("ClientsToCity")[0]);
                        PropertyInfo nestedprop = item.GetType().GetProperty("ClientCity");
                        nestedprop.SetValue(item, obj, null);
                    }
                    else if (c.ColumnName == "CountryID")
                    {
                        object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Country));

                        SetItemFromRow<Country>(obj as Country, row.GetChildRows("CityToCountry")[0]);
                        PropertyInfo nestedprop = item.GetType().GetProperty("CityCountry");
                        nestedprop.SetValue(item, obj, null);
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        // function that creates an object from the given data row
        public static T CreateItemFromRow<T>(DataRow row) where T : new()
        {
            T item = new T();

            SetItemFromRow(item, row);

            return item;
        }

        // function that creates a list of an object from the given data table
        public static List<T> CreateListFromTable<T>(DataTable tbl) where T : new()
        {
            List<T> lst = new List<T>();

            foreach (DataRow r in tbl.Rows)
            {
                lst.Add(CreateItemFromRow<T>(r));
            }

            return lst;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code looks awesome, BUT doesn't fit very well to my case, I don't have any DataRelation. I'll save it for future reference, this is a nice looking code. 
Brotip: This code would run very slow, because of the `property.SetValue` you used. I would create a compiled function for the getters and setters (maybe only setters) using Expressions and cache it.